# Where to add C wire on transformer?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I want to add a C wire to support a smart thermostat.  The existing wire is 2-conductor (R+W).  I can run a new 18/3 easily, but I don't see an obvious place to attach the new C wire on the burner/transformer side.

The control is a Hydrostat 3150.  The thermostat is connected to terminals marked T + T (which correspond to R + W on the thermostat end), but I don't see any other identifiable low-voltage wires.  The transformer is soldered to the PCB board but it's clearly visible, and if I were sure which wire to use, I could probably just put an alligator clip on it.  I am pretty sure (from the circuit diagram) that all the rest of the screw connectors (L1 L2 C1 C2 B1 B2 ZC ZR) are 120VAC.

Is there a place I can tap into the hot 24V output of the transformer for a C wire?  Or is adding another transformer the best bet?

Answer (score 1):

### You'll need to use another transformer

Your control does not provide any access to the C terminal of the transformer, as per the [ladder diagram in the manual](https://fwwebbimage.fwwebb.com/ProductInfo/HydroStat-3150-Inst.-061515-final.pdf).  As a result, you'll need to run something more than a 3-wire cable, with the new transformer connecting to Rc/C on the thermostat and the existing T-T terminal wiring connecting to Rh/W on the thermostat.

Comment: Outstanding -- exactly what I needed, and thanks for the pointer to the ladder diagram, which I don't recall having seen.  I'll add a 24V transformer.  Thanks for the great response.

Comment: @GregHoward since this seems to have resolved your problem, please click the check-mark so others know it's been resolved.